# How to parse addresses from website specifying class in R?

Tags: html, css, r, rvest, xml2

I would like to parse addresses of all stores on the following website:
https://www.carrefour.fr/magasin/region/ looping through the regions. So starting for example with the region "auvergne-rhone-alpes-84", hence full url = https://www.carrefour.fr/magasin/region/auvergne-rhone-alpes-84. Note that I can add more regions afterwards, I just want to make it work with one for now.

```
carrefour <- "https://www.carrefour.fr/magasin/region/"
addresses_vector = c()

for (current_region in c("auvergne-rhone-alpes-84")) {
  current_region_url = paste(carrefour, current_region, "/", sep="")
  
  x <- GET(url=current_region_url)
  
  html_doc <- read_html(x) %>%
    html_nodes("[class = 'ds-body-text ds-store-card__details--content ds-body-text--size-m ds-body-text--color-standard-2']")
  
  addresses_vector <- c(addresses_vector, html_doc %>%
                          rvest::html_nodes('body')%>%
                          xml2::xml_find_all(".//div[contains(@class, 'ds-body-text ds-store-card__details--content ds-body-text--size-m ds-body-text--color-standard-2')]") %>%
                          rvest::html_text())
}
```

I also tried with  `x%>% read_html() %>% rvest::html_nodes(xpath="/html/body/main/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/ol/li[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]")%>% rvest::html_text()` (copying the whole xpath by hand) or `x%>%read_html() %>%html_nodes("div.ds-body-text.ds-store-card__details--content.ds-body-text--size-m.ds-body-text--color-standard-2") %>%html_text()` and several other ways but I always get a `character(0)` element returned.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a couple of custom functions to help then use `purrr` to map the store data function to inputs from the output of the first helper function.

First, extract the region urls and extract the region names and region ids. Store these in a tibble. This is the first helper function `get_regions`.

Then use another function, `get_store_info`, to extract from these region urls the store info, which is stored in a `div` tag, from which it is dynamically extracted when JavaScript runs in the browser, but not when using `rvest`.

Apply the function that extracts the store info over the list of region urls and region ids.

If you use `map2_dfr` to pass both region id and region link to the function which extracts store data, you then have the region id to link back on to join the result of the `map2_dfr` to that of region tibble generated earlier.

Then do some column cleaning e.g., drop ones you don't want.

```
library(rvest)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(jsonlite)

get_regions <- function() {
  url <- "https://www.carrefour.fr/magasin"
  page <- read_html(url)
  regions <- page %>% html_nodes(".store-locator-footer-list__item > a")
  t <- tibble(
    region = regions %>% html_text(trim = T),
    link = regions %>% html_attr("href") %>% url_absolute(url),
    region_id = NA_integer_
  ) %>% mutate(region_id = str_match(link, "-(\\d+)$")[, 2] %>%
    as.integer())
  return(t)
}

get_store_info <- function(region_url, r_id) {
  region_page <- read_html(region_url)
  store_data <- region_page %>%
    html_node("#store-locator") %>%
    html_attr(":context-stores") %>%
    parse_json(simplifyVector = T) %>%
    as_tibble()
  store_data$region_id <- r_id
  return(store_data)
}

region_df <- get_regions()

store_df <- map2_dfr(region_df$link, region_df$region_id, get_store_info)

final_df <- inner_join(region_df, store_df, by = 'region_id') # now clean columns within this.
```

Comment: Thank you a lot @QHarr! It solves my problem, even though the map2_dfr doesn't work, as coordinate columns are character in one df and double in the other. I only need to parse information from three of the regions though, so I just select them by hand and use your ```get_store_info()``` function.

Comment: What changes do you need me to make please? What data type do you need columns as? map2_dfr does work as intended. So I need to address whatever the real problems are please.